# Expected success of trial with conditions

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expectation, markov-process

Assume that $n$ people want to achieve a task T. One person can try, and is successful with probability $p$. But when a person try all the other have to do an other trial to have the right to challenge $A$ with probability of success $q$ (we can assume that $p=q$ if it's easier).

More formally I have a Markov chain on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ with initial state $(n,0)$ ($n$ is the number of person that want to try and 0 is the number of success for T).

And from $(n',r)$ the probability in one step to reach $(k,r+1)$ is $$p{n'-1 \choose k} q^k(1-q)^{n'-1-k}$$
And the probability in one step to reach $(k,r)$ is $$(1-p){n'-1 \choose k} q^k(1-q)^{n'-1-k}$$

I want to know the expected number of person achieving T depending on $n$ the number of people present in the beginning. I have no idea on how to compute that.

Even a limit or even better matching at the limit upper and lower bound would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly.  If $X(t)$ is the number of people who want to try at stage $t$, then $X(0) = n$ and the conditional distribution of $X(t+1)$ given $X(t)$ is binomial with parameters $X(t)-1$ and $q$.  If $T$ is the first $t$ where $X(t) = 0$, then conditional on $T$ the number of successes $S$ is binomial with parameters $T$ and $p$.  You want $E[S] = p E[T]$.

By a first-step analysis, $E[T] = f(n)$ where $f(0) = 0$ and for $n \ge 1$,
$$f(n) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose j} q^j (1-q)^{n-1-j} f(j)$$
It seems $f(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n(n-1)/2$ in $q$.  The first few values are

$$ \eqalign{
f(0) &= 0\cr
f(1) &= 1\cr
f(2) &= q+1\cr
f(3) &= {q}^{3}-{q}^{2}+2\,q+1\cr
f(4) &= {q}^{6}-{q}^{5}-{q}^{4}+4\,{q}^{3}-3\,{q}^{2}+3\,q+1\cr
f(5) &= {q}^{10}-{q}^{9}-{q}^{8}+5\,{q}^{6}-3\,{q}^{5}-5\,{q}^{4}+10\,{q}^{3}-
6\,{q}^{2}+4\,q+1\cr}$$
I don't see a closed form.

The coefficients of the first few powers of $q$ have a tantalizing regularity:
it looks like for $n \ge 1$
$$f(n) = 1 + {n-1 \choose 1} q - {n-1 \choose 2} q^2  + {n \choose 3} q^3 - {n \choose 4} q^4 + \ldots $$
But the coefficient of $q^5$ breaks the pattern: it is
$(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n^2-4n-20)/120$

If $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) z^n$ is the generating function of $f(n)$, 
I get a functional equation:
$$ \eqalign{g(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{n=j+1}^\infty {n-1 \choose j} q^j (1-q)^{n-1-j} f(j) z^n\cr
&= \dfrac{z}{1-z} + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{ z^{j+1} q^j}{(1-(1-q) z)^{j+1}} f(j)\cr
&= \dfrac{z}{1-z} + \dfrac{ z}{1 - (1-q) z} g\left(\dfrac{qz}{1-(1-q)z}\right)}$$
but again I don't see a way to a closed form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I a bit sad that there are no closed forms ... Do you think there is any chance of bounding $f(n)$? I came up with this because I wanted a way to bound the expected number of people achieving T (plus some other constraint that are fulfilled by this construction). If you have an idea of a similar MC in which you can bound this it would be good to. Thanks again